# select all from table1 with zero entries in table2 in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, union, outer-join

Consider 2 tables, user and contact:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(36)
);

CREATE TABLE contact (
    id INT,
    phone INT,
    userID INT
);

INSERT INTO user (id,name) VALUES 
(1,'Frank'),
(2,'Henry'),
(3,'John')

INSERT INTO contact (id,phone,userID) VALUES 
(1,911,1),
(2,922,2),
(3,933,2)
```

I am interested in all user entries that do not have any contact.

The outer join of these tables returns 4 results:

```
SELECT contact.*, user.*
FROM   contact 
       LEFT JOIN user 
          ON contact.userID = user.id
UNION ALL
SELECT contact.*, user.*
FROM   user
       LEFT JOIN contact
          ON contact.userID = user.id
WHERE  contact.userID IS NULL
```

How do I select all user where contact.userID is null (1 result, in this example)?

Comment: Your second subquery does this.  Don't you see that?

Comment: You are right, I should have seen that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your second subquery:

```
SELECT c.*, u.*
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     contact c
     ON c.userID = u.id
WHERE c.userID IS NULL;
```

It does exactly what you want, although I would remove the `c.*` from the `SELECT`.